# Season ending of Jericho

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, jericho

At the end of season 2 of Jericho (last season before it got shut down) are we as viewers meant to assume that hawkins is alive or dead? He was shot pretty badly and was bleeding for atleast 2 hours maybe 3 until he received any medical attention. They did this big scene where he said he was glad to be dying for a good cause, but the last scene he seems to still be hanging on a little when he finally got medical care.

Also, one last small question: They brought the nuke to Texas to be able to fight the cheyenne government and it ends all happy lovey, etc... Do they intend on using the Nuke on the war against the Cheyenne government or dismantle it and fight a "normal" war that could cost millions of people their lives? Or is the Cheyenne government suppose to magically give up because they no longer have the one nuke that proves their involvement in the destruction of America.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure about Hawkins; the season was being wrapped up ridiculously quickly and many loose ends were left. Personally, I think he was going for the martyr route but survived anyway as a hero with a happy ending.

In regards to the bomb, it wasn't so much that the bomb would be used as a weapon. Instead the bomb was evidence that would be used to convince Texas not to side with Cheyenne. Texas was identified as the swing state meaning whoever it chose to back would rule without question. So by presenting the bomb, Texas would "see sense" and not back Cheyenne and therefore Cheyenne would topple when Texas sided with their enemy.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks Craig. ANd yeah, I agree, it was wrapped up very very quickly. The first few episodes the of show made it seem like it was going to be so good, then midway season 2 I found out the show was cancelled at one point and I only have a few episodes left and I was like "whattt?!?!". They even only described about 2 years of Jakes past and didn't even say what he did for the other 3 (2 years working for the mercenaries or whatever in Iraq), he was supposedly a driver, but can do things a driver would never be trained in such as saving the girl in the bus in episode 1. Thanks again!

Comment: The reason for the rushed ending was that the show was actually cancelled after the first season due to poor ratings. However, it was a cult hit and a number of fans protested the network to get another season commissioned. This happened; it got another 7 episodes. But it got cancelled again after the second season, hence why it all got wrapped up prematurely and so many corners were cut.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, however, you may be interested in checking out the [Jericho comic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jericho_Season_3%3a_Civil_War). It picks up as a comic book version of season 3. So, if you're a Jericho fan and interested in finding out more about what happens, I'd look into this. As a note, although I do have the comic, I haven't read it yet so I honestly don't know how good it is!

Comment: Ah, sounds interesting. I will have to take a look at that :) Hopefully it's some what good :p

Comment: There is also a Season 4 comic now, and possibly more coming, so fans of Jerchio: don't lose hope!